# Use of recordAccess(this) in Entry<K, V> class

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

While having a look inside HashMap class, I came across this method :-

```
    /**
     * This method is invoked whenever the value in an entry is
     * overwritten by an invocation of put(k,v) for a key k that's already
     * in the HashMap.
     */
    void recordAccess(HashMap<K,V> m) {
    }
```

Actually, this method is defined inside the inner class of `Entry<K, V>`

I'm not able to make out of that comment. What does this method do ?

PS : I can also see this method being called inside's HashMap's putForNullKey() method

```
 private V putForNullKey(V value) {
        for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
            if (e.key == null) {
                V oldValue = e.value;
                e.value = value;
                e.recordAccess(this); // call
                return oldValue;
            }
        }
        modCount++;
        addEntry(0, null, value, 0);
        return null;
    }
```

UPDATE : I've updated the first code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A LinkedHashMap can have two orders: insertion order, or access order. If access order is used, this method makes sure that the accessed entry is moved to the beginning of the list.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more ? Why it is called from inside HashMap's method ?

Comment: That's an implementation detail. In order to mutualize code between HashMap and LinkedHashMap, the base Map.Entry defines this method (which does nothing by default) and the HashMap calls it. In LinkedHashMap, this method is overridden to maintain the access order.

Comment: Check my edit. recordAccess() is a do nothing method inside HashMap's Entry inner class.

Comment: That's what I just said. By default, in HashMap, it does nothing. It's overridden in LinkedHashMap to maintain access order. Nearly all the code of LinkedHashMap is in HashMap, and this method is there only because LinkedHashMap needs it.