# HashMap Entry class's recordAccess() method is empty body

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

The API has its comment like this..

But what does it do? Since it has empty body method.

```
/**
 * This method is invoked whenever the value in an entry is
 * overwritten by an invocation of put(k,v) for a key k that's already
 * in the HashMap.
 */
void recordAccess(HashMap<K,V> m) {
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of recordAccess(this) in Entry<K, V> class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703668/use-of-recordaccessthis-in-entryk-v-class)

Comment: read the answer already...not satisfactory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It exists to be overridden by subclasses. It is invoked when records are accessed. The `LinkedHashMap` subclass overrides this method and uses it to move frequently accessed records to the front of the linked list.

Comment: but why then the put method call it in HashMap ?

Answer (score 3):

It has a method body in the `Entry` subclass used by `LinkedHashMap` (which is a subclass of `HashMap`). The method exists in the base `Entry` class in order to be able to use common code in the base `HashMap` class. But since access record is useless in `HashMap`s that are not `LinkedHashMap`s, the method doesn't do anything.

Comment: but in this case the method was called from Entry object of  HashMap class...which is empty ?

Comment: HashMap and LinkedHashMap share some methods. LinkedHashMap needs to record access, but HashMap does not. So they both record access, but HashMap uses an Entry class which does nothing when recording the access, whereas LinkedHashMap uses an Entry subclass which overrides the method to actually record the access.

Comment: thats what , override is ok , but why to call it...it if does nothing...because it does not make sense for HASHMAP then why to call it from put method

Comment: Because the same method is also used by the LinkedHashMap subclass, which needs to record access.

Answer (score 0):

In JDK7 ,there is no put method in LinkedHashMap ,but override the class Entry, which means  put elements in LinkedHashMap will call HashMap's put,but use recordAccess of LinkedHashMap